# z-index not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I have two navbars inside `#mobile-header` that I want to get the page content to scroll behind.   I can't get it working.

Here is a [JS Fiddle for the sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/denisefield/ks2q1abg/12/)

And here is the code

```
<div id="mobile-header">
  <div class="top-header"></div>
  <div class="navbar-inverse"></div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap"></div>
```

and the css

```
.top-header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#mobile-header {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

#page-wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
}
```

can anyone help

Comment: What does `I cant get it working.` mean? What is the expected output? What is failing? Any errors?

Comment: its not scrolling, sorry for being unclear

Comment: Looks like it's scrolling in your Fiddle...

Comment: I have set up on my website like that and its not working? https://www.thatsinsurance.online/demoarmentum_data/help-center/ if you check 768px

Comment: You were missing some semicolons in the `#mobile-header` definition after `left` and `right` - is that the problem? - https://jsfiddle.net/skqpcxcm/

Comment: thanks titus to you too. Have done the revised code, added the semi colons and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. I have modified some part of CSS.

```css
.top-header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#mobile-header {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0 right:0 top:0;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  top: 0px;
}

#page-wrap {
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-header">
  <div class="top-header"></div>
  <div class="navbar-inverse"></div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap"></div>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ahmed  thanks thats almost it, but I want the red bit to go behind rather than over it, can you help

Comment: Hi @DeniseField, Please check it now. I have set red bit to go behind the mobile header section.